# C++ char * Confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am fairly new to C++ and am trying to understand pointers. Why does the following code output asdf instead of the memory address of a? From my understanding, a pointer is a variable that stores a memory address of type, in this case, char. So wouldnt printing p simply print the memory address of the first character?

```
int main()
{
    char *p="asdf";
    cout<<p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's [an overload of `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) taking `const char*` and interpreting it as pointing to a NUL-terminated C-style string (because it's a common thing to want to do). There's [another overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) taking `void*` and printing the address. Therefore, if it's the address you want, just do `cout << static_cast<void*>(p);`

Comment: cout<<p unwrapping the pointer value if you want to print address you need to cout<<*p it will print address of the point rather than the value , you also study about the & operator and * operator.